# Categorizing resources in RESTful URIs

Tags: rest, restful-url

I have following three resources for an API which provides throttling related information to users.

```
GET /throttling/api-policies
GET /throttling/application-policies
GET /throttling/configuration
```

Since all the three resources are related to throttling "/throttling" has been used to categorize them under throttling.

Is this a bad practice to use those types of verbal nouns to categorize resources? I know we are always encouraged to use nouns as much as possible instead of verbs, but the use of verbal nouns is not very common.

Comment: Throttling is a noun. Technically, a gerund or verbal noun. It's fine.

Comment: @MikeTaverne thanks, I have edited my question.